# how can I loop the code to print the next string from my json file specifically the Email field. PYTHON

Tags: python, json

python code

```
import json

while True:
    with open('SNS DETAILS.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        no = 0
        print(data[no]['Email'])
```

I want it to loop the code and print the next email field, then loop and print the one after that and loop and print the next one after, etc.

Hers the JSON data:

```
[    
    {
        "Email" : "",
        "Password" : ""
    },
    {
        "Email" : "",
        "Password" : ""
    }
]
```

Comment: @Mark Meyer please write the full code as this is a bit too vague for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who doesn't know how to do it, here's now.
just change the 100 to the highest number that you want to loop.

```
import time
import json
x = -1
while x<100:
    x += 1
    time.sleep(10)
    with open('SNS DETAILS.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        number = 0
        print(data[x]['Email'])
```

Comment: This is a **really** bad solution. You open, read, and close the file 100 times. You only need to do that once. I'll post some code showing a different option.

Comment: @Mark Meyer thanks for that they both do the same thing but yours is cleaner and much more simpler, I appreciate the help.